# Serving ember app from IIS resulting in UnrecognizedURLError

Tags: javascript, iis, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to serve an ember app from IIS.

I created a new app using `ember new my-app` and then ran `ember build --environment production`. This generated the files in the `dist` directory as expected.

On the IIS side, I added a new website on the server and mapped the `dist` folder from the last step.

Now, when I navigate to `localhost/index.html` I get a blank page.

I checked the source of the page and the js files are being served correctly as expected. This would mean that it's the templates that are not being retrieved correctly. In the chrome inspector console there is an exception which says `Uncaught: UnrecognizedURLError: /index.html`. The ember inspector says 'Ember application not detected!'.

I've tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3861), but none has worked for me.

Has anyone else experienced this problem/know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you make it work without  the ```index.html``` part?

Comment: Hi keo. I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean have IIS automatically serve index.html at localhost/?

Comment: Yes, it will not solve your problem probably, but at least it will work.

Comment: Yes, it won't solve the problem. And the page is being served fine like I mentioned. It's the handlebars templates that are not being served( I think).

Comment: It's not problem with handlebars, the app crashes because of url/server. Thats why ember inspector says ```Ember application not detected!``` - it didn't boot up.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not sure what exactly your solution is. Would you mind formulating it into an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91873/discussion-between-keo-and-jeevan-jose).

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember Router uses `location: history` by default. This means, it assumes that `/index.html` is your route. But obviously it's not defined so the router throws `UnrecognizedURLError`.

There are several solutions for your problem:

1. Set `locationType: 'hash'` in `config/environment.js` of your ember application. This will force Ember router to use `#` in url for routing and in your case this would be like `localhost/index.html#your/route`.
2. Configure your IIS instance to handle `index.html` as a default document. To do this, open your server config and make sure it has the key:

[image]

3. Change ember build config to produce `index.aspx` instead of `index.html`. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32592394/5309656).

Comment: Also, be sure you've created a Site in IIS and not a virtual directory. The latter will cause URLs that reference the site root (any URL beginning with "/") to look for documents/routes at the root of the site that your virtual directory is a child of.

Comment: It worked indeed. It is a bit weird though. I had already tried changing locationType to 'hash' and 'auto' and it hadn't worked. Changing it to 'hash' again did the trick for me. Thanks.